# Select comma sperated column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get comma `,` separated column value in SQL Server.

```
Select 
CT.ClaimTypeId, CT.ClaimTypeName,CT.MHWSchemeNo,CT.MHWClaimTypeID,CFCTR.FormId,CF.Name,
FF.FormId,FF.FieldId,FF.Label,FF.Name,FF.IsDefaultField,FF.IsFieldLabelVisible,FF.IsRequired,FF.Type,

Label = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' +JFFO.Label
          FROM dbo.FormFieldOption JFFO
          where JFFO.FieldId = FF.FieldId
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
Value= STUFF((
          SELECT ',' +JFFO.Value
          FROM dbo.FormFieldOption JFFO
          where JFFO.FieldId = FF.FieldId
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
AdditionalTextfieldName= STUFF((
          SELECT ',' +JFFO.AdditionalTextfieldName
          FROM dbo.FormFieldOption JFFO
          where JFFO.FieldId = FF.FieldId
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

from EmployeeClaimTypeRelationship ECR 
LEFT JOIN ClaimType CT on CT.MHWSchemeNo=ECR.MHWSchemeNo
LEFT JOIN ClaimFormClaimTypeRelationship CFCTR on CFCTR.ClaimTypeId=CT.ClaimTypeId
LEFT JOIN ClaimForm CF on CF.FormId=CFCTR.FormId
LEFT JOIN FormField FF on FF.FormId=CFCTR.FormId
LEFT JOIN FormFieldOption FFO on FFO.FieldId=FF.FieldId
where ECR.MHWUserId='CITITEST1'
group by FF.FieldId,CT.ClaimTypeId, CT.ClaimTypeName,CT.MHWSchemeNo,CT.MHWClaimTypeID,CFCTR.FormId,CF.Name,
FF.FormId,FF.FieldId,FF.Label,FF.Name,FF.IsDefaultField,FF.IsFieldLabelVisible,FF.IsRequired,FF.Type
```

This is my query. And it is giving me the correct result. Here I'm using `group by` clause.

Now I want to optimize this query.

As you can see above, I have 3 columns which have comma `,` separated values which are coming from same table.

Is there any way so that I don't have to write multiple time same query for different fields?

Like this

```
Select 
CT.ClaimTypeId, CT.ClaimTypeName,CT.MHWSchemeNo,CT.MHWClaimTypeID,CFCTR.FormId,CF.Name,
FF.FormId,FF.FieldId,FF.Label,FF.Name,FF.IsDefaultField,FF.IsFieldLabelVisible,FF.IsRequired,FF.Type,

Label = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' +JFFO.Label
          FROM dbo.FormFieldOption JFFO
          where JFFO.FieldId = FF.FieldId
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),
Value,AdditionalTextfieldName = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' +JFFO.Value as Value,','+JFFO.AdditionalTextfieldName as AdditionalTextfieldName
          FROM dbo.FormFieldOption JFFO
          where JFFO.FieldId = FF.FieldId
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

from EmployeeClaimTypeRelationship ECR 
LEFT JOIN ClaimType CT on CT.MHWSchemeNo=ECR.MHWSchemeNo
LEFT JOIN ClaimFormClaimTypeRelationship CFCTR on CFCTR.ClaimTypeId=CT.ClaimTypeId
LEFT JOIN ClaimForm CF on CF.FormId=CFCTR.FormId
LEFT JOIN FormField FF on FF.FormId=CFCTR.FormId
LEFT JOIN FormFieldOption FFO on FFO.FieldId=FF.FieldId
where ECR.MHWUserId='CITITEST1'
group by FF.FieldId,CT.ClaimTypeId, CT.ClaimTypeName,CT.MHWSchemeNo,CT.MHWClaimTypeID,CFCTR.FormId,CF.Name,
FF.FormId,FF.FieldId,FF.Label,FF.Name,FF.IsDefaultField,FF.IsFieldLabelVisible,FF.IsRequired,FF.Type
```

Comment: Can you please highlight or point out the difference?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : I don't want to use Stuff Again and again. see In second query I'm using `Value,AdditionalTextfieldName`

Answer (score 1):

You could have a view.

```sql
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ...
```

(Instead of *, you might prefer to select the union of all columns you ever might need and possibly give them aliases.) Then you would only need to

```sql
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM view_name
WHERE [additional conditions]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a UDF Table-Valued Function and call that, it will also give you some performance benefit

**Function Definition**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_FormFieldOptionList ( @FieldId INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
SELECT DISTINCT 
     Label = STUFF((
              SELECT ',' +JFFO.Label
              FROM dbo.FormFieldOption JFFO
              where JFFO.FieldId = FF.FieldId
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    ,Value= STUFF((
              SELECT ',' +JFFO.Value
              FROM dbo.FormFieldOption JFFO
              where JFFO.FieldId = FF.FieldId
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    ,AdditionalTextfieldName= STUFF((
              SELECT ',' +JFFO.AdditionalTextfieldName
              FROM dbo.FormFieldOption JFFO
              where JFFO.FieldId = FF.FieldId
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

FROM dbo.FormFieldOption FF
WHERE FF.FieldId = @FieldId )
```

**Your Query**

```
Select 
CT.ClaimTypeId, CT.ClaimTypeName,CT.MHWSchemeNo
,CT.MHWClaimTypeID,CFCTR.FormId,CF.Name
,FF.FormId,FF.FieldId,FF.Label,FF.Name
,FF.IsDefaultField,FF.IsFieldLabelVisible
,FF.IsRequired,FF.Type,f.Label. f.Value ,f.AdditionalTextfieldName 

from EmployeeClaimTypeRelationship ECR 
LEFT JOIN ClaimType CT on CT.MHWSchemeNo=ECR.MHWSchemeNo
LEFT JOIN ClaimFormClaimTypeRelationship CFCTR on CFCTR.ClaimTypeId=CT.ClaimTypeId
LEFT JOIN ClaimForm CF on CF.FormId=CFCTR.FormId
LEFT JOIN FormField FF on FF.FormId=CFCTR.FormId
OUTER APPLY  dbo.fn_FormFieldOptionList(FF.FieldId) f
where ECR.MHWUserId='CITITEST1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in this query, we are joining dbo.FormFieldOption twice. Good optimization & speed can be achieved if we can restructure the query. Try to restructure the join
towards table **dbo.FormFieldOption** to single.

Comment: How can I do this.